# Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException

Tags: java, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk, restfb

I am running a simple code using restFB API, after i create the token access, the program was running, retrieving the data from my Facebook account, but after a while i got this message of exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1376380800. The current unix time is 1376392638.
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:766)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:688)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:630)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:592)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:556)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchObject(DefaultFacebookClient.java:244)
    at Example.main(Example.java:19)
```

The code that I run that produces the exception mentioned above is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("Token_Access_Code");

    User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
    Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("cocacola", Page.class);

    System.out.println("User name: " + user.getName());
    System.out.println("Page likes: " + page.getLikes());

}
```

Has anyone experienced an exception like this before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to regenerate the access token.i have faced the same error, even though the access token is supposed to last as for 60 days as per FB documentation. check this link :

**http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending**